# Pinterest Tag Error: 'load' command was called multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont have any pinterest code/ tags  in my website,
However I keep getting this error message in my browser console.
How can I figure out the origin of my error  [Browser Console Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4TN3.png)

Thanks

Comment: This is the start of the error message -  react_devtools_backend.js:2273 Pinterest Tag Error: 'load' command was called multiple times.  Previously for tag id '2614232848233', now for tag id '2614232848233'.

Comment: Browser extension? If you don't have any pinterest code on the site, first thing to check is disable all extensions and see if you still get an error.

Answer (score 0):

The handiest way of debugging react applications is to have [React Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) on browser.